# PHP shows not correct number of posts

Tags: php, wordpress

For one of my (wordpress) projects I have an event page that shows all upcoming events. The problem is, I need to show only 2 'future' events.

I now have: 5 events in total, 3 in the past (shouldn't display anymore) and 2 future events (should display). When I use the showposts => 2 no future posts are being displayed, when I do showposts => 5, the 2 future events do display.

How can I fix that only 2 future events will be displayed?

```
    <?php
    $months = array("", "januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni", "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december");
    query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'showposts' => 5) );
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php

    $dateparts = explode("-",get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date')[0] );
    $date = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date')[0];
    $event_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date);
    $now = new DateTime() ;
    $past_event = ($event_date <= $now);

      if(!$past_event){
        ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try by printing both date before going into that condition so you will more clear about it that date is correct and in same format or not

Comment: query_posts is modify main query don't use it

Answer (score 0):

Create a secondary loop and meta query on 'date' fields.I hope this will helpful.

```
 <?php 
            $event_query = new WP_Query(
            array( 
              'post_type'   => 'event',
              'meta_key'    => 'date', 
              'order_by'        => 'date',
              'order'       => 'asc',      
              'meta_query'  => array(
                 array(         
                  'key'     => 'date', 
                  'value'   => date("n"),
                  'compare' => '>=',      

                ) 
               ) 
              ) 
            ); 

     ?>
       <?php while($event_query->have_posts()): $event_query->the_post();  ?>
```

Comment: Hi Vasim, this looks good but how will I create the second loop? Can you expand my code as example?